# Oracle: materialized view with unique items out of flat table

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I am working on Oracle. I have this large property-indexer table (`THE_TABLE`), whose columns are

```
[ObjectID | CategoryID | Property1 | Property2 | ... | PropertyN]
```

where `N` is known by design. All the `Property%` columns are VARCHAR2 of the same size, the ObjectID is Numeric. Now, I would like to create a materialized view that contains the results of the following queries:

```
select distinct CategoryID, (select 'Property1' from dual) as PropertyName, Property1 as PropertyValue from THE_TABLE

select distinct CategoryID, (select 'Property2' from dual) as PropertyName, Property2 as PropertyValue from THE_TABLE

...

select distinct CategoryID, (select 'PropertyN' from dual) as PropertyName, PropertyN as PropertyValue from THE_TABLE
```

In other words, the view (`THE_VIEW`) should contain three columns:

```
[CategoryID | PropertyName | PropertyValue]
```

and be able to return the unique values linked to a specific CategoryID. Is there a way to create such a view?

Please note that I do not have the possibility to modify `THE_TABLE`.

Regards,
Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sufe if I understand your question correctly, but I believe you want something like

```
create materialied view THE_VIEW as
  select categoryID, 'property1' propertyName, property1 propertyValue from THE_TABLE union all
  select categoryID, 'property2' propertyName, property2 propertyValue from THE_TABLE union all
     ...
  select categoryID, 'propertyN' propertyName, propertyN propertyValue from THE_TABLE
;
```

Comment: Guess you should use `union` instead of `union all` to get the distinct values?

Comment: Thanks René, this solves my problem perfectly (in my case, the union and union all keywords make no difference: by design, there can be no common rows between two queries).

Regards, Andrea

Comment: @Andrea: `UNION` would also remove common rows within one of the queries (as does the distinct in your example). BTW: If you like this answer, you can also up-vote it to give René some extra reputation.

Comment: @Peter: I don't have the required reputation to upvote, but I will come back when I will :) From the performance point of view, which solution is better between (1) distinct in the single queries and union all, and (2) no distinct and union?

Comment: @Andrea: I see, `+1` for your questions to give you some reputation :) I would suggest to test this with your data, but I did a test and (2) took twice the time of (1), so with my test-data using `DISTINCT` and `UNION ALL` was the better choice.

Comment: `union all` is usually the better choice because `union` normally involves a sorting of the returned data in order to find duplacate rows. `union all` doesn't sort the data but rather just emits them as they are retrieved from the select statements. This behaviour is, however, not mandated by any standard.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Oracle 11g, you can try the new pivot/unpivot features.

This [article](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506) is an excellent read on this, but in general you'd want an UNPIVOT in this case.  For example (I'm not on an 11g instance at the moment, so this is a generic example):

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM   pivoted_data;

JOB           D10_SAL    D20_SAL    D30_SAL    D40_SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
CLERK            1430       2090       1045
SALESMAN                               6160
PRESIDENT        5500
MANAGER          2695     3272.5       3135
ANALYST                     6600

5 rows selected.


SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM   pivoted_data
  3  UNPIVOT (
  4               deptsal                              --<-- unpivot_clause
  5           FOR saldesc                              --<-- unpivot_for_clause
  6           IN  (d10_sal, d20_sal, d30_sal, d40_sal) --<-- unpivot_in_clause
  7          );

JOB        SALDESC       DEPTSAL
---------- ---------- ----------
CLERK      D10_SAL          1430
CLERK      D20_SAL          2090
CLERK      D30_SAL          1045
SALESMAN   D30_SAL          6160
PRESIDENT  D10_SAL          5500
MANAGER    D10_SAL          2695
MANAGER    D20_SAL        3272.5
MANAGER    D30_SAL          3135
ANALYST    D20_SAL          6600

9 rows selected.
```

Another option for those on 11g.